# my device got a ROM flash by the seller prior to my purchase?

Tags: rom-flashing, factory-reset, file-system, date-and-time, warranty

I bought a Galaxy Tab S6 a few days ago and I am going to verify if it is really brand-new.

Some facts: The production date of this device is in July 2020 and my purchase date is in February **2021**.

First of all, the system date and time is not up-to-date and even confusing. The system date (on the day of my purchase: February 19, 2021) was January 3, 2019 (**that is, 7 mounths prior to August 2019 when this device model released by the manufacturer for the very first time**).

Besides, the system time doesn't match the device region (UAE) local time and there is about 9 hours difference.

Finally, dates of files in Android folder are mostly January 1, 2019 (**which indicates two days prior to my purchase and boot up**) and other file dates are for two days later (January 3, 2019) corresponding to when I purchased and booted the device.

Therefore I'm going to conclude that the seller might had flashed ROM into this device a couple days before he sold it to me and this device is not brand-new.

What is your opinion?

Comment: The dates you mentioned doesn't match. Based on those dates you have bought the device in 2019.

Comment: Sorry, I bought it in February **2021** but on the day of my purchase when I booted up the device, the Android system date was January 3, 2019

Comment: By the way your question can be answered very easy: All devices come in a sealed package. If the seal is broken the device is not "brand new" independently on the software that is installed, the Knox state or whatever you aske din the last days.

Comment: The seal was not broken but it could be a fake seal. I bought from  third-party seller.

Comment: I actually wouldn't be concerned about the time "issue"... The time and date would go back to the default of the kernel until network time could sync. In tablets this is sometimes not enabled by default. If the device had been off long enough, it would "lose" it's internal time and revert to the default time and date (00:00 @ 1/1/2019)  at boot until a network sync and time zone had been configured.

Comment: To my knowledge, file dates in Android folder are the same as when a device is booted up for the very first time and after that they get last modification date.

Comment: By my logic, I believe that this device was flashed and booted up (and perhaps factory reset) by the seller two days prior to my purchase. My reason is that if I were the very first person who booted up the device (and we suppose that your scenario is the case), all file dates in Android folder would have to be 1/1/2019 soon after I booted the device for my very first time.

Comment: But this is not the case as I see some file dates (in Android folder) remain 1/1/2019 and the others are 1/3/2019 which reflect last modify date as the results my very first boot up. So there must be an initial boot up two days prior to when I booted up for my very first time.

Comment: Can't this convince you?

Comment: @acejavelin It seems you have followed my posts in the few last days. I returned my first device to local warranty company and they swapped it with one that has both unbroken Samsung seal and local warranty company seal. In this post I'm referring to my **second** tablet. The first tablet had Samsung seal but broken and local warranty seal unbroken.

Comment: If you are that worried, just return it and buy one from a seller you believe is more reliable.